# Display result counts on Views exposed filters with Ajax

Tags: views

*I don't ask a lot of questions here. Actually this is my first one here, so if anything is wrong I apologise.*

I'm working with Drupal 7, Views and Better exposed filters.

- I created a view with multiple exposed filters based on taxonomy terms.
- I also have a hook: form_views_exposed_form_alter that that adds the number of results to the taxonomy labels.

  ```
  foreach ($form['#info'] as $filters => $filter) {
  $filter_val = $filter['value'];
  $db_table = "field_data_" . str_replace("_tid", "", $filter_val);
  foreach ($form[$filter_val]['#options'] as $tid => &$value) {
      if ($tid != "All") {
          $query = db_select($db_table, 'f')
            ->condition('f.'.$filter_val, $tid)
            ->condition('f.bundle', $type);
      } else {
          $query = db_select("node", "f")
              ->condition('f.type', $type);
      }

      $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
      $count = $query->execute()->fetchField();
      $value .= ' (' . $count . ')';
  }
  ```

  }

Now When I select an option Ajax is used to update the view. But I want to update the result counts aswel.

I tried to add an #ajax callback to the form['apply'] in my form_views_exposed_form_alter function but that doesn't seem to do anything. I tried to echo/print in the callback function but nothing happens, not even an error.

```
$form['apply']["#ajax"] = array(
    'callback' => '_exposed_form_callback',
    'wrapper' => $form["#build_id"]
);

function _exposed_form_callback(&$form, &$form_state)
{ 
 ...
}
```

How can I do this?